# Generate combinations without replacement

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

I'm trying to calculate the combinations of a vector of factors in R.
I have used the "gtools" package however i'd ideally like it to return where the order is not important i.e "Age" "Gender" is not repeated for "Gender" "Age". Only 1 of those is taken.

[image]

```
variables <- c("Age","Gender","Segment1","Segment2","Segment3","TransactionDate","TransactionMonth","TransactionYear","Tenure")
require(gtools)
permutations(n=3,r=2,variables,repeats.allowed = FALSE)
```

Extra if possible, is it possible to scale up n and r so that the population of Variables increases and the pick of variables also increases (example below) without manual adjustment?

[image]

Thanks for any advice at all!

Comment: `permutations()` returns permutation patterns. `combn()` returns combination patterns (with a wide format, so I used `t()` to change it into  a long format). `t(combn(variables, 3))`

Comment: Wonderful @cuttlefish44